# Direct limit preserves exactness - question on the proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, limits-colimits

Consider a short exact sequence of directed systems of modules $$0\rightarrow (A_i)\overset{(\Phi_i)}{\rightarrow} (B_i)\overset{(\Psi_i)}{\rightarrow} (C_i)\rightarrow 0,$$ i.e. every $$0\rightarrow A_i\overset{\Phi_i}{\rightarrow} B_i\overset{\Psi_i}{\rightarrow} C_i\rightarrow 0$$ is short exact, $f_{ji}\circ\Phi_i=\Phi_j\circ f_{ji}$ and $f_{ji}\circ\Psi_i=\Psi_j\circ f_{ji}$ for all $i\le j$.

One can show that then $$0\rightarrow \varinjlim A_i\overset{\Phi}{\rightarrow}\varinjlim B_i\overset{\Psi}{\rightarrow}\varinjlim C_i\rightarrow 0$$ is short exact, where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are constructed and unique by the universal property.

Recall that for a direct system $(M_i,f_{ji}:M_i\to M_j)$ we have $$\varinjlim M_i=(\bigoplus_i M_i)/U,$$ where $U$ is spanned by $m_i-f_{ji}(m_i)$, $i\le j$.

In our lecture we have proven that $\Phi$ is injective but I have an issue in understanding the proof. It goes like this:

Let $\varinjlim A_i\ni a=\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j a_j\right]$ with $\Phi (a)=0$, $a_j\in A_{i_j}$. Since we have a directed system we can find $k\ge i_1,...,i_n$, hence $a=[a_k]$ for a $a_k\in A_k$. By assumption $\Phi(a)=[\Phi_k(a_k)]=0$, hence $\exists N\ge k$ such that $f_{Nk}(\Phi_k(a_k)))=0$. Since $\Phi_N$ is injective and $0=f_{Nk}(\Phi_k(a_k))=\Phi_n(f_{Nk}(a_k))$, get $f_{Nk}(a_k)=0$, thus $a=[a_k]=[f_{Nk}(a_k)]=0$.

My questions are:

1. Why do we have $a=[a_k]$ for some $a_k\in A_k$?
2. Why is $\Phi(a)=[\Phi_k(a_k)]$ and why is there such an $N$?
3. Why is $[a_k]=[f_{Nk}(a_k)]$?

**EDIT:** For example $\ker\Psi\subset\text{im}\Phi$. Assume we have $\Psi(b)=0$ for $b=[\sum b_{i_j}]$, $b_{i_j}\in B_{i_j}$. If we chose $k\ge i_1,...,i_n$, we get $b=[b_k]$ for a $b_k\in B_k$. Hence $$0=\Psi (b)=\Psi ([b_k])=\Psi (h_k (b_k))=h_k (\Psi_k (b_k))\in\varinjlim C_i,$$ where $h_k$ is the natural map $C_k\to\varinjlim C_i$. Since $h_k (\Psi_k (b_k))\in\varinjlim C_i$, we get $h_k (\Psi_k (b_k))=h_N(c_N)$ for some $N$. But $\Psi_N$ is surjective thus there is a $b_N\in B_N$ such that $h_k (\Psi_k (b_k))=h_N(\Psi_N(b_N))=\Psi (h_N(b_N))$.

Two questions:
Is my chosen $N$ greater or equal to $k$? How can I conclude?

Comment: 1. Commutativity of diagram says you can always push $a_k$ down to larger $A_l$ with $l\geq k$. It is always a finite sum. So sum over elements in $A_l$ and take its class. 2. $\Phi$ is induced from each $\Phi_k$. You can repeat similar argument to $B_i$ to obtain this. 3. Commutativity of diagram.

Comment: There's a typo in your definition of $U$ (otherwise, $f_{ii}(m_i) = m_i$ would alway be $0$ in the limit). Isn't it rather  "$U$ is spanned by $\{m_i - m_j \mid \exists k \geq i,j, f_{ki}(m_i) = f_{kj}(m_j)\}$ " ? I'll try to answer your questions once you've answered this

Comment: @Max I have addited my question, thanks for the hint

Comment: The thing you prove in your edit (after a few minor modifications) is that $\Psi$ is surjective, you will not get to $\operatorname{Ker}\Psi \subset \operatorname{Im}\Phi$ this way. To prove that, you need to see what it means for an element to "become $0$" in the limit. Assume $[m_i]= 0$. Then by the characterization I gave, there exists $j\geq i$ such that $f_{ji}(m_i) = f_{ji}(0)= 0$. Thus being $0$ in the limit is the same as having one of your images under the $(f_{ji})_{j\geq i}$ equal to $0$

Comment: But this is exactly what I do not understand. Why there is such an $j$? And why does $[m_i]=0$ implies $m_i=0$ (you use this in $f_{ji}(m_i)=f_{ji}(0)$.)

Comment: Have you give up on me? :(

Comment: Sorry, you have to add "@Max" for me to see your comments on here. To see why there is such a $j$, you need to see that "$a=b$ in the limit if and only if $f_{ki}(a) = f_{kj}(b)$ for some $k\geq i,j$" where $a\in M_i, b\in M_j$.

Comment: And $[m_i]=0$ does not imply $m_i=0$, it implies $f_{ji}(m_i)=0$ for some $j\geq i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You take $a = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n a_{i_l} / U$ (I'll write $/U$ to denote the class mod $U$) where $a_{i_l} \in M_{i_l}$, by definition of the direct sum. Taking $k\geq i_1,...,i_n$, which is possible because $I$ is a directed system. Then $a_{i_l} /U = f_{k i_l}(a_{i_l})/U$ by definition of $U$, so that $a = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n  (f_{k i_l}(a_{i_l})/U)$. But this is also $(\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n  f_{k i_l}(a_{i_l}))/U$, which is $a_k/U$ with $a_k = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n  f_{k i_l}(a_{i_l}) \in M_k$. So $a=a_k/U$ for some $k$ and $a_k \in M_k$.
2. $\Phi(a) = \Phi(a_k /U)$. But $a_k/U$ is the image of $a_k$ in the morphism $\iota_k : M_k \to \operatorname{Lim} M_i$ (sorry I don't know how to write the arrow). So $\Phi(a) = \Phi\circ \iota_k (a_k)$. But the commutativity of the associated diagrams in the definition of $\Phi$ from the $\Phi_i$'s implies that $\Phi\circ \iota_k =j_k \circ \Phi_k$ where $j_k : B_k \to \operatorname{Lim}B_i$ is the canonical morphism.

Thus denoting $V$ the same thing as $U$ but for the $B_i$'s, you get indeed $\Phi(a)= \Phi_k(a_k) /V$.

This is a general property of limits of directed systems : if $m_i / U = 0$, then there exists $N \geq i$ with $f_{Ni}(m_i) = 0$. If you look at the characterization of the limit I gave in the comments, this is quite clear.

3. $a_k/U = f_{Nk}(a_k)/U$ by definition of $U$ ! We have $a_k -f_{Nk}(a_k) \in U$ by definition.

I hope I've answered your questions, if you have others, don't hesitate to ask them.

EDIT : I have shown that $\Phi$ was injective. Now to show that the sequence $0\to A\to B \to C\to 0$ is exact, it suffices to show two things : $\operatorname{Ker}\Psi = \operatorname{Im}\Psi$ and $\Psi$ is surjective.

Remember that one has, for a given $N$ a commutative diagram $j_N\circ \Phi_N = \Phi\circ \iota_N$.

So let $b\in \operatorname{Im}\Phi$. $b = \Phi(a)$. But also, $a=\iota_N(a_N)$ for some $N, a_N$ so that $b= j_N\circ\Phi_N(a_N)$. So $\Psi(b) =\Psi\circ j_N\circ \Phi_N(a_N)$.

But looking at the definition of $\Psi$, we get $\Psi\circ j_N = g_N\circ \Psi_N$ where $g_N : C_N\to C$. Therefore, $\Psi(b) = g_N\circ \Psi_N\circ\Phi_N(a_N)$. Since $0\to A_N\to B_N\to C_N\to 0$ is exact, we get $\Psi(b) = 0$, which shows $\operatorname{Im}\Phi\subset \operatorname{Ker}\Psi$.

As for the converse, assume $\Psi(b) = 0$. Write $b= b_k/V$, so that $\Psi\circ j_k(b_k) = 0$ . Again, looking at the definition of $\Psi$ and the commutative squares that go with it, we get $g_k\circ \Psi_k(b_k) = 0$.

Denoting $w_{Nk} : C_k\to C_N$ when $N\geq k$, this last equality implies the existence of $N\geq k$ with $w_{Nk}\circ \Psi_k(b_k) = 0$ (with the characterization of the limit I gave in the comments).

The commutative diagrams that are given in the hypothesis give $\Psi_N\circ g_{Nk}(b_k)=0$ where $g_{Nk} : B_k\to B_N$ when $N\geq k$.

Since the sequence at index $N$ is exact, we get $g_{Nk}(b_k) \in \operatorname{Im}\Phi_N$. Write it as $g_{Nk}(b_k) = \Phi_N(a_N)$. Applying $j_N$ leads to $j_N\circ g_{Nk}(b_k) =  j_N\circ \Phi_N(a_N) = \Phi\circ \iota_N(a_N)$ (this last equality holding because of the commutatuve diagrams in the definition of $\Phi$).

So $j_N\circ g_{Nk}(b_k) \in \operatorname{Im}\Phi$. But this is $g_{Nk}(b_k)/V = b_k/V = b$.

Therefore $\operatorname{Ker}\Psi\subset \operatorname{Im}\Phi$, which, in conclusion, give us $\operatorname{Ker}\Psi = \operatorname{Im}\Phi$.

The same sort of abstract nonsense leads to the surjectivity of $\Psi$ (I'm a bit tired so if I made any typo or serious mistake, or left some nontrivial details out in the above proof, please let me know)

2nd EDIT : 
I'm adding this image for a bit more (hopefully) clarity. The notations are a bit unfortunate but those are the ones I went with so might as well go all the way.
[image]

Hopefully this diagram will help you see the situation a bit more clearly : the "circle arrows" indicate that the cell commutes. The outer cells commute by definition of a direct limit, the inner lower cell commutes by definition of a directed system, and the inner upper cell commutes by definition of $\Psi$ (it was defined to be the unique arrow making it commute). What matters for the surjectivity of $\Psi$ is actually the commutativity of the upper inner cell, but drawing the whole diagram seemed a good way of summing up the situation.

What I'm saying in the comments is that if $c\in \varinjlim C_i$, then $c = g_j(c_j)$ for some $j$: but $\Psi_j$ is surjective, so $c = g_j\circ \Psi_j (b_j)$ for some $b_j$. According to the diagram I've drawn, $g_j\circ\Psi_j = \Psi\circ j_j$, so thqt $c\in \operatorname{Im}\Psi$

Comment: The answer is perfect. By the way \varinjlim gives $\varinjlim$. Is it now easy to conclude that $\Psi$ is injective and $\ker \Psi =\text{im}\Phi$?

Comment: Ah thanks for the LaTeX tip ! You probably mean $\Psi$ is surjective. I can help you with that but I think if you try to do similar arguments, using the diagrams that define $\Phi, \Psi$ and the definition of the limit, you should manage to prove it .

Comment: I guess I need your help for this, I can show anything of the three last things :(

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why do we have $a=\iota_N (a_N)$ for some $N$? Do you mean $[a_N]$?

Comment: Yes, $\iota_N(a_N)= a_N/U = [a_N]$ are all different notations for the same thing. The proof that $a= \iota_N(a_N)$ for some $N, a_N$ is the same as usual: wirte $a= \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n a_{i_l}/U$, but if $N\geq i_l$ for all $l$, then $a_{i_l}/U = f_{N i_l}(a_{i_l})/U$ by definition, and so $a= \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n f_{Ni_l}(a_{i_l})/U$. But letting $a_N = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^n f_{Ni_l}(a_{i_l})$, this is exactly what we want (note that I'm a bit fuzzy on where the $/U$ is, no parentheses, but this is not a problem, because the congruence mod $U$ commutes with addition)

Comment: Thank you! What are your maps $\iota$ and $j$ by the way?

Comment: I've written them down in the answer : $\iota_N : A_N \to \varinjlim A_i$ is the canonical map, and $j_N$ is similar for $B_N$ and $\varinjlim B_i$

Comment: Thanks but I still have problems in seeing why your map $w_{Nk}$ exists?

Comment: In fact there are 2 more problems: 1) The existence of that map $w_{Nk}$ and the surjectivity of $\Psi$ which I am not really able to show. So if I have an $c\in\varinjlim C_k$ then I doesn't have any more equations in order to use some commutativity arguments

Comment: $w_{Nk}$ exists as it is a given hypothesis: remember that $(C_i)_{i\in I}$ is a directed system with arrows $w_{ji}: C_i \to C_j$ whenever $i\leq j$. If you have $c\in \varinjlim C_k$ you can write it as $c_N/W$ for some $N$ and $c_N \in C_N$, and $W$ is the same as $U$ but for $C$. Using the surjectivity of $\Psi_N$ and the commuting diagrams that are given in the definition of $\Psi$ will do the trick (not forgetting that $g_N(c_N) = c_N/W$ by definition). It should be simple if you write down the diagrams

Comment: Alright, I have understood the surjectivity, but I do not at all understand the existence of that $w_{Nk}$ :( Why has your $N$ be $\ge k$? And I only get $g_k(\Psi(b_k))=...=\Psi(g_N(b_N))=\Psi (f_{MN}(b_N))$ for some $M\ge N$.

Comment: $w_{Nk}$ is given, in the definition of the directed system $(C_i)_{i\in I}$. It's what you called $f_{ji}$ in the general context where the directed system is $(M_i)_{i\in I}$. As for "I only get...", you can't get $g_k\circ\Psi$ because $\Psi$ has codomain $C$, whereas $g_k$ has domain $C_k$

Comment: You are right, sorry. But how do I get this map anyway?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean that I am not able to understand your argument for the existence of the map $w_{Nk}$, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, to understand it, can you precisely define the notion of a directed system of modules ?

Comment: Of course: A partially ordered set $I$ is called directed if there is only one arrow $i\to j$ for all $i<j$ and $i\to i$ is the identity. Besides we want that for every $i,j\in I$ there is a $k\ge i,j$. A system $(M_i)_i$ is called directed system of modules if the index set is directed and there are maps $f_{ji}:M_i\to M_j$ which $f_{ki}=f_{kj}\circ f_{ji}$ for all $i\le j\le k$.

Comment: Precisely ! Well here, what I called $w_{Nk}$ is what you call $f_{Nk}$, except that $w_{Nk}$ is for the directed system $(C_i)_{i\in I}$

Comment: Right, but what is the $N$? And why is this $N$ greater or equal to $k$?

Comment: I have added an 'EDIT' to my original question post. My problem should become clearer now :)